# Aggregate weekly monthly data using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I need to aggregate daily table to weekly and monthly dynamically.

**DAILY_TABLE:**

```
----------------------------------------------
 SECTOR | AREA | STVAL |        HRDATE
----------------------------------------------
   USJ  |  TD  |   8   | 17-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TJ  |   4   | 17-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TD  |   8   | 18-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TJ  |   4   | 18-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TD  |   8   | 19-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TJ  |   4   | 19-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TD  |   8   | 20-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TJ  |   4   | 20-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TD  |   8   | 21-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TJ  |   4   | 21-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TD  |   8   | 22-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TJ  |   4   | 22-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TD  |   8   | 23-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TJ  |   4   | 23-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TD  |   8   | 24-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TJ  |   4   | 24-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TD  |   8   | 25-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TJ  |   4   | 25-OCT-2015 00:00:00
```

**WEEKLY_TABLE:**

```
----------------------------------------------
 SECTOR | AREA | STVAL |        HRDATE
----------------------------------------------
   USJ  |  TD  |  16   | 18-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TJ  |   8   | 18-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TD  |  56   | 25-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TJ  |  28   | 25-OCT-2015 00:00:00
```

**MONTHLY_TABLE:**

```
----------------------------------------------
 SECTOR | AREA | STVAL |        HRDATE
----------------------------------------------
   USJ  |  TD  |   72  | 25-OCT-2015 00:00:00
   USJ  |  TJ  |   36  | 25-OCT-2015 00:00:00
```

Suppose, this procedure does not run this week, but runs the next week, it must aggregate the earlier week and current week data as well.

**EDIT 1:**

```
SELECT CAST( MIN([HRDATE]) AS VARCHAR(20))
       +' TO '
       + CAST( MAX([HRDATE]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS HRDATE,
       SUM(STVAL),
       SECTOR,
       AREA 
  FROM DAILY_TABLE
 GROUP BY HRDATE
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT[HRDATE]) = 7;
```

Comment: SELECT CAST(MIN( [HRDATE]) AS VARCHAR(20))+' TO '+CAST (MAX([HRDATE]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS HRDATE,
           SUM(STVAL),SECTOR,AREA
    FROM   DAILY_TABLE . I am new to sql .
    GROUP BY HRDATE
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT[HRDATE])=7

Comment: Do you need pure SQL solution or PL/SQL procedure?

Comment: sql or pl/sql both will do

Comment: `[HRDATE]` is an invalid identifier in SQL - and will not work on Oracle. Also `+` is only there to add numbers, not to concatenate strings (for that you would need `||` in SQL). Are you sure you are using Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two procedures to do weekly and monthly accounting, respectively. They are similar and differ only in table names and calculation of the "the last day of a period".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE make_week_accounting IS
  l_last_date DATE;
  -- the day you want to be the last in the week >> 1=SUNDAY, 2=MONDAY and so on
  c_week_end_day  CONSTANT NUMBER := 1; 
  c_long_time_ago CONSTANT DATE := DATE '1900-01-01';
BEGIN

 SELECT nvl(MAX(hrdate), c_long_time_ago) INTO l_last_date FROM weekly_table;

 INSERT INTO weekly_table(sector, area, stval, hrdate)
 SELECT sector, area, SUM(stval), month_end
   FROM (
          SELECT sector, area, stval, trunc(next_day(hrdate, c_week_end_day)) AS week_end
            FROM daily_table
           WHERE hrdate > l_last_date
        ) 
  GROUP BY sector, area, week_end;

END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE make_month_accounting IS
  c_long_time_ago CONSTANT DATE := DATE '1900-01-01';
BEGIN

 SELECT nvl(MAX(hrdate), c_long_time_ago) INTO l_last_date FROM monthly_table;

 INSERT INTO monthly_table(sector, area, stval, hrdate)
 SELECT sector, area, SUM(stval), month_end
   FROM (
          SELECT sector, area, stval, trunc(last_day(hrdate)) AS month_end
            FROM daily_table
           WHERE hrdate > l_last_date
        ) 
  GROUP BY sector, area, month_end;

END;
/
```

Comment: I am noy able to use next_day or last_day nor dateadd . any alternative?

Comment: @jo_develop, I don't see why you can't use them if you work under Oracle.

Comment: This will work. But can we extend this logic so that I can run the weekly and monthly aggregation on daily basis?

Comment: This is not working for some cases. Suppose area is "null", then it is not considering that row. It must aggregate that as well.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd267/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE DAILY_TABLE ( SECTOR,AREA,STVAL,HRDATE ) AS
          SELECT 'USJ', 'TD', 8, DATE '2015-10-17' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TJ', 4, DATE '2015-10-17' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TD', 8, DATE '2015-10-18' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TJ', 4, DATE '2015-10-18' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TD', 8, DATE '2015-10-19' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TJ', 4, DATE '2015-10-19' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TD', 8, DATE '2015-10-20' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TJ', 4, DATE '2015-10-20' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TD', 8, DATE '2015-10-21' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TJ', 4, DATE '2015-10-21' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TD', 8, DATE '2015-10-22' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TJ', 4, DATE '2015-10-22' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TD', 8, DATE '2015-10-23' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TJ', 4, DATE '2015-10-23' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TD', 8, DATE '2015-10-24' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TJ', 4, DATE '2015-10-24' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', NULL, 4, DATE '2015-10-24' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TD', 8, DATE '2015-10-25' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', 'TJ', 4, DATE '2015-10-25' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USJ', NULL, 4, DATE '2015-10-25' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SECTOR,
       AREA,
       SUM(STVAL) AS STVAL,
       TRUNC(HRDATE,'IW') AS HRDATE
FROM   DAILY_TABLE
GROUP BY 
       SECTOR,
       AREA,
       TRUNC(HRDATE,'IW')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd267/1/0)**:

```
| SECTOR |   AREA | STVAL |                    HRDATE |
|--------|--------|-------|---------------------------|
|    USJ | (null) |     8 | October, 19 2015 00:00:00 |
|    USJ |     TD |    16 | October, 12 2015 00:00:00 |
|    USJ |     TJ |     8 | October, 12 2015 00:00:00 |
|    USJ |     TD |    56 | October, 19 2015 00:00:00 |
|    USJ |     TJ |    28 | October, 19 2015 00:00:00 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT SECTOR,
       AREA,
       SUM(STVAL) AS STVAL,
       TRUNC(HRDATE,'MM') AS HRDATE
FROM   DAILY_TABLE
GROUP BY 
       SECTOR,
       AREA,
       TRUNC(HRDATE,'MM')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd267/1/1)**:

```
| SECTOR |   AREA | STVAL |                    HRDATE |
|--------|--------|-------|---------------------------|
|    USJ |     TJ |    36 | October, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
|    USJ | (null) |     8 | October, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
|    USJ |     TD |    72 | October, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: This is not working for some cases. Suppose area is "null", then it is not considering that row. It must aggregate that as well.

Comment: How is it "not working"? I have just updated the SQLFIDDLE with `NULL` values and it is aggregating them - if you want a different behaviour then you will have to describe your problem better (and ask it as a new question).